# What would postgres do to SQL functions with a guessed cost?

Tags: postgresql

e.g.

```
create or replace function sss(arg)
    returns bool
    as 'xxx', 'yyy'
    language c;
create or replace function sssss(arg)
    returns bool
    as 'select sss($1)'
    language sql
    cost 100;
```

then when i call `select * from table where sssss(col) and ttttt(col)`, how would the cost of sssss(col) be calculated?

I heard that the sql functions would be inlined for postgres, however, after expanding the sql, the cost 100 info would be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function `sssss` is inlined, the cost will be assumed to be 1 (the default cost for C language functions).

The idea is that inlining a function replaces it with its definition, and then the optimizer examines the resulting query to get a better estimate.

If the `COST` setting is relevant for you, you should define `sss` with a `COST` of 100. If you cannot do that, because `sss` is a system function, make sure that `sssss` cannot be inlined, for example by defining it as `STRICT`.